# Absolute Coordinate positioning of Signhere Tabs

Tags: docusignapi

My application typically displays documents at 300 DPI. My understanding from research is that DS typically displays documents at 72 DPI, so when my user is specifying a location they'd like to place a signhere tab in my software, i convert the coordinate location before handing it off to the DS ReST API.

I am finding that while my X coordinate comes out correctly, my Y coordinate is off. Is 72DPI the correct display i should be adjusting for when passing in my SignHereTab coordinates?

Comment: The `SignHere` and `InitialHere` tabs are "special" compared to the other tabs, in that they have an additional y-offset after placement (this is to help align the signature line).  I believe it's a constant offset, though.  Are you seeing differing results each time, or does the vertical height always seem to be off by the same amount?

Comment: Hi Ergin, i believe it is scaling slightly but it's hard to tell. Can you give me the value of the constant offset in pixels? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure and not in a good place to test, but I think it's probably around 10 pixels or so.  As mentioned it should be happening for all sign and initial here tabs, so once you zero in on it you should be able to always use that value...

Answer (score 3):

The specific Y offsets (both at 72dpi):

- `SignHere`: 21
- `InitialHere`: 16

Comment: Any official documentation to support those values ?