# Tabs X&Y position discrepancy

Tags: docusignapi

Several days ago, I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051435/signature-initials-signaturedate-tabs-location-issue) why there is a difference between signature/tabs vs date tab location.
Apparently this is due to an offset.
However, I am having another location issue with the any type of tabs.
As you can see in my json request, I have placed 2 tabs at 576 pixels. In the photo, none of them are placed at the 576 location, am I missing another offset ?

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "LPL_251_PRELIMINARY DISCLOSURE STATEMENT MARY MUSIC",
      "fileExtension": "PDF",
      "documentFields": [
        {
          "name": "label",
          "value": "DOCUMENT-628"
        },
        {
          "name": "VendorName",
          "value": "XXXX"
        },
        {
          "name": "FileRoom",
          "value": "FI Bank"
        },
        {
          "name": "Institution",
          "value": "01"
        },
        {
          "name": "SmartIndexFieldName",
          "value": "Transaction_Date"
        },
        {
          "name": "COMMENT",
          "value": "XXXXX"
        },
        {
          "name": "Document_Name",
          "value": "Preliminary Disclosure Statement: Mary Music"
        },
        {
          "name": "File_Name",
          "value": "LPL_251_PRELIMINARY DISCLOSURE STATEMENT MARY MUSIC.PDF"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cabinet",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "Type",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "Account_Number",
          "value": "987987978"
        },
        {
          "name": "Transaction_Date",
          "value": "06-29-2015"
        }
      ],
      "documentBase64": "..... }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "scaleValue": "0.6",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "2",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "45",
              "yPosition": "576"
            }
          ],
          "dateSignedTabs": [
            {
              "bold": "True",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "2",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "80",
              "yPosition": "576"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": "Mary Music",
        "email": "Mary.Music@mailinator.com",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "accessCode": "1234",
        "requireIdLookup": "False",
        "customFields": [
          "ROLE-4"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "editors": [
      {
        "name": "Joseph Szupiany",
        "email": "Joseph.Szupiany@mailinator.com",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "accessCode": "1234",
        "requireIdLookup": "False",
        "customFields": [
          "PARTY-3"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  "templateRoles": [],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this document from your Tesla",
  "notification": {
    "expirations": {
      "expireEnabled": "True",
      "expireAfter": "4"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24998864/1219543) for the offset values associated with tabs

Comment: Thanks, is that documented on the DocuSign side ? I haven't found anything in the developer section

Comment: Sorry these offsets are not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Different tabs behave differently because of their visual implementation.

The specific Y offsets (both at 72dpi):

SignHere: 21
InitialHere: 16

I would also recommend you consider moving from v2 to v2.1 of the API where we made improvements in this area.